# How to show different error jsp page by intercepting request on the JSP page in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am working on Spring MVC controller project. I have different JSP pages around 7-8 jsp page.

People will make a call to these different JSP pages from different IP address, meaning from different different machines.

Now what I am trying to do is - I will intercept the call and extract the IP Address from it and if the IP Address is in our valid list, then only I will show the jsp page they are requesting otherwise I will show an error jsp page.

Now there is another tricky situation here. I don't want to do above check on all the JSP pages I have, I just want to do that only on two JSP page. Meaning if the people are requesting those two JSP pages, then only I will do the above check otherwise I don't want to do the above IP Address check.

Below are my two jsp code in which I need to have the above IP Address check. Meaning if people are requesting below jsp page from the IP Address which is not in our list, I would like to show an error jsp page.

Below is my `testWorkflow.jsp` -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testWorkflow", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
ZookeeperResponse testWorkflow(@RequestParam("workflow") final String workflow,
    @RequestParam("conf") final String value, @RequestParam("dc") final String dc) {

    // if ipAddress is not in the valid list
    // then show error jsp page.

    // some code here related to my JSP page


    }
```

Below is my `testOperation.jsp` -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testOperation() {

    // if ipAddress is not in the valid list
    // then show different error jsp page.

    // some code here related to my JSP page

    }
```

And below is the code I can use to extract the IP Address from the header -

```
//is client behind something?
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
if (ipAddress == null) {  
   ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
}
```

Now I am not sure what I should do to restrict the invalid ip address in making the call and show them the error jsp page if they are not valid. I need to show different error jsp page for the above two jsp page call.

Is this possible to do? And what is the best way to achieve this? I just started working with Spring MVC controller so not sure what the options I have and what is the best way for my problem?

Any suggestions and example will be of great help.

**Note:-**

I already have Valid IP Address list in the code itself. So I don't need to define those valid IP Address in a file or xml somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some thing simple and can solve your problem.

You can use an interceptor, it doesn't require any external module.

Code:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();
        //Only check on several pages not all
        //Check if user is requesting the two JSP pages
        if (requestUri.startsWith(...)) {
        //Yes, user is requesting the two JSP
            if(/*Check if ip address is on the list*/) {
                //Yes, it is.
                 if (/*check sth else maybe?*/) {
                      //test passes
                      return true;
                 } else {
                      //test fails.
                      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "error_1";
                       return false;
                 }
            } else {
                //oops, not on the list, redirect to error url
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "error_2";
                return false;
            }

        } else {
        //no need to check, just grant access
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Config is also simple:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="loginInterceptor" class="....LoginInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Now, assume the user's ip address is not on the list, he or she is redirected to error page url (say `abc.com/error_denied`). Here, I assume you don't have a controller mapped to that url, then `<mvc:view-controller path="/error_denied" view-name="error.jsp"/>` will do the job :)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I was not sure earlier how to read whether the call is coming for which jsp page. So you saying, I can get that from `getRequestURI` method? Cool.. And also how would I show the `error1.jsp` page for invalid request coming for `testWorkflow.jsp` page and `error2.jsp` for invalid request coming for `testWorkflow.jsp` page.. Is this possible to do anyhow? I already know valid ip addresses so I can do if check but not sure how to show different error JSP page for different calls.

Comment: Also, can we instead of doing `requestUri` check add some exclusion list in the interceptors as well? Just asking.

Comment: say, I have url "`http://localhost:8080/hello`" `getRequestURI` will give /hello and `getRequestURL` will give the entire URL, I usually prefer `getRequestURI`.  Therefore, you can intercept the call and have a peek, if it is going to the url where you will checking, then check in code, otherwise just return true, there is no need to check. If user fails the test, return false will deny access (redirect to 403).

Comment: @user2809564 In terms of displaying customized 403 page, I usually do this trick: send a error code (403 in your case) and in config: `<mvc:view-controller path="/error1_url" view-name="error1.jsp"/>  <mvc:view-controller path="/error2_url" view-name="error2.jsp"/>` this is a simple Spring MVC view controller, it simply shows given page when given url is accessed.

Comment: @user2809564 Some trick in your case, since you have 2 different error pages, make use of that `HttpServletResponse` e.g.: `response.sendRedirect("error_url")`. Please bear me for my long comments. These tricks together should be able to solve your peoblem in a simple clear way.

Comment: These are really useful tricks. I am slightly confuse on the error jsp page you just told me. If you can provide me an example how would I show different error pages for invalid request for two jsp page then it can help me to understand better. :(

Comment: @user2809564 Please see the updated answer. Sorry for typing so slow, it is very hard to keep code in shape on StackOverflow.  I didn't go into details of your checking logic, so it may not be exactly what you will write (e.g. where to redirect etc.).

Comment: @user2809564 Sorry, I'm at work place right now. Chatting pages are banned and I can't see it. If you want to redirect users to different error pages based on different error, you just have to add more detailed if-else statement in the body of the interceptor. I will put that in the answer now.

Comment: Thanks.. Instead of showing `error_2 jsp page` for second jsp, can we show a JSON error response for that jsp by any chance?

Comment: @user2809564 I doubt if we can do that in this situation (from an interceptor). It is more doable for us to give a JSON response from a controller.

Comment: Sure but how to make a JSON response from a controller then in this situation? Can we notify controller that we need to pass an error message in the  JSON response?

Comment: Or can we add this json response in the jsp which I am showing? Basically, I want to show this error json response `{"response":"You are not authorized to make a call.","error":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","status":"ERROR"}`

Comment: @user2809564 There is a work around. We can have a controller mapped to the error url you want. When sending the response, add some information in the session. When the user is actually redirected t to the error url, our error controller will be doing the return-view work. At this point of time, we can extract the previously set variable in the session and do sth base on it (e.g. send a customized JSON response or sth).